# language or language specification and audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Failed audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4608651.

In the question, it appears the author wants to design an API and asked for a language or a language specification. I think the answer could also be a favorite algorithm or grammar, too.

I think the question falls into the *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...*.

Perhaps this question should not be an audit question.

Anyway, I'm not worried about the occasional fail from something like this. Just trying to avoid potential future confusion for others. And I understand some folks like talking about algorithms.

Comment: related: [Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773) "While there is no "officially implemented" solution for this, one can use whatever means are at their disposal now in order to bring the "human factor" to audits selection. When you spot a slippery audit, go straight to the "item" it uses and do the action _opposite to audit direction_..."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you find an audit question like that, visit the question and cast a vote; that way it will no longer be used as an audit, *and* you'll give the community a chance to review the post in the same light you did.

I agree here that this is a tool recommendation question; I've voted to close it as such.

Comment: I've found several like that, I didn't know casting a vote makes it disappear from the audits. Thanks!

Comment: Huh. Shouldn't audits only have questions with a) no downvotes, b) 2 upvotes, c) not reviewed or flagged, and d) accepted, upvoted twice answer? I don't like the algorithm they use now.

Comment: @bjb568: That post had 5 upvotes, no downvotes, and had not received close votes or flags. I don't think accepted and upvoted answers would weed out false positives many more false positives, really.

Comment: @Martijn If it already has a good accepted answer, it is more likely to be a good question.

Comment: @bjb568: we have a badge for answering a bad question with a great answer even. No, a good accepted answer doesn't necessarily mean the question was all that good. And remember that the post used in *this specific case* had 5 upvotes! That's a lot of upvotes for a question that really should have been closed! These are edgecases, really, there are *thousands* of audits conducted each day, we don't see many of exceptions like this one.

Comment: FWIW, single vote may be not sufficient to drop the post off the audits, see [Post I voted down and close is shown to me as known good audit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203663/165773)

Comment: Interesting; did you come across this any more recently? I've personally have not been presented with audits like that myself.